# uialertview glossy look and feel

Tags: ios, xcode5, uialertview

I have created a uialertview

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                                message:@"In-App Purchase is disabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[alert show];
```

Which creates a dialog as below

[image]

But I need something like

[image]

How do I get this glossy look and feel ? Working in iOS 7.1, xocode 5.

My app uses UIWebView,  UIViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will look glossy as seen in that image on `iOS 6` and lower OSs. `iOS 7` is now flat.

Now if you wish to create your own `UIAlertView` by subclassing it. Theres a few tutorials that will teach you how to. but you'll need to create your own graphics and will cause a extra programming.

All your custom drawing will have to be inside the `drawRect` or overriding the various elements in the `UIAlertView`.

I would look at the way this github project does it's own customization to the `UIAlertView`
https://github.com/Sumi-Interactive/SIAlertView

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The non glossy UI goes with IOS 7, I have an old app which has IOS 6 as the target version - it has the glossy alert views in an IOS 6 device (iPhone 3GS) but once running in an IOS 7 device it follows the new format.,   If it is really important you may want to simulate UIAlertviews using modal subviews  .... [self presentViewController: mediaUI animated: YES completion:NULL];  or pop view controllers if coding for iPad.

Here is an old sample code :  https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView